# Why is the network Input stream not working more than once?

Tags: java, network-programming, inputstream

The network input stream works correctly in version 1 of the code below in that it continues to receive data messages from the server.
However, in version 2, only the first message is received and then nothing.

Why doesn't it work? Is there an alternative?

Version 1

```
 public void run(){
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
     }catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Version 2

```
 public void run(){
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        while(true){
                String msg = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
     }catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Comment: And there *are* newlines in the stream you send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second version won't work because you're not checking for end of stream. `readLine()` returns null at that point. It should be:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

... and it will only return a line when it reads a line, including a line terminator. If you don't send lines it can't read lines.

Comment: That was it. The server wasn't sending lines and there was no check for the end of the stream. Thank you EJP. I won't forget that lesson.